# Session Storing Images for Temporary and retrive and store into model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, session-variables, temporary-files

I've been searching for long time of solving the limitation in ***asp file uploading*** as the case in my question [File Upload: Fail to assign value into File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092028/file-upload-fail-to-assign-value-into-file-keep-poping-null-to-me-need-help), it still not answered by anybody. At this moment, can i know is there anybody here know how to use **session** to store an image for temporary, and thereafter retrieve it back to the stream and put it into the **model**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for it. ;)

```
        if (model.File != null && model.File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            Byte[] destination1 = new Byte[model.File.ContentLength];
            model.File.InputStream.Position = 0;
            model.File.InputStream.Read(destination1, 0, model.File.ContentLength);
            model.BankSlip = destination1;
            Session["info.file"]= model.File;//storing session.
        }
        else
        {
            //retrieving session
            var myImg1 = Session["info.file"] as HttpPostedFileBase;
            model.File = myImg1;
            Byte[] data=new Byte[myImg1.ContentLength];
            myImg1.InputStream.Position = 0;
            myImg1.InputStream.Read(data, 0, myImg1.ContentLength);
            model.BankSlip = data;
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                   
            DepositControllerLog.ErrorException("DepositController - LocalBank(Post) - AddAttachment(refreshed) - ", ex);
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the image into a byte array then convert it to a base64 string and save that into the session.  Then convert it to a byte array and bind it to your control.

Comment: example now i have the file is in the model.file
the type is httppostedfilebase, how i should convert it to byte array? or can  it directly store in session?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852102/convert-httppostedfilebase-to-byte

once you have the byte array you;

string str = convert.toBase64String(bytearr);

Comment: the one we talking is storing or retrieving? sorry to ask

Comment: i think we are talking about storing right, i done for that wht about retrieving?
by the way izzit correct?

Comment: MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                model.File.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                byte[] data = target.ToArray();
                string place = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
                Session["File1"] = place;

Comment: i try using the session variable to assign it to model.file, but it keep fail me saying that cannot convert object to httpfilebase. do you have any idea. BTW, you know why i want to assign it back to model.file right?

Comment: Well you have to convert it back to the format you want it.  So now its just a string so now convert the string back into a byte array and stream it back into the model.file format.